# Keeping only the lines with the cursors in multiple-cursors

Tags: multiple-cursors

Say we have a file with several cursors. Not all lines have cursors, but every cursor is on a different line.

How can I kill all the lines without cursors? I couldn't find a single `mc` command for this, but maybe there is a still a way to do it with the other commands?

Comment: One approach is to append lines with `mc` to a register, clear the whole buffer and paste in that appended register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function creates messages only, instead of actually deleting anything.  If this approach seems appealing, then `(message "No real or fake cursor here:  %s" line)` can be substituted with `(kill-region pbol peol)` to kill the line and place it into the kill-ring. If the user wishes to also remove the `\n` at the end of the line, then use `(kill-region pbol (1+ peol))`.  The section of code `(message "MC exists:  %s" line)` can be replaced with `nil` so that the function is silent in its operation.  This function should only run one time, so it is added to the list of `mc--default-cmds-to-run-once`.

```
(defun mc/kill-all-lines-without-cursors ()
"Kill all lines that do not have fake or real cursors."
(interactive)
  (let* (
      mc
      line
      pbol
      peol
      (starting-line (line-number-at-pos))
      (my-list
        (mapcar
          (lambda (x)
            (cons (mc/cursor-beg x) (mc/cursor-end x)))
          (mc/all-fake-cursors))))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (catch 'done
        (while t
          (setq line (line-number-at-pos))
          (setq mc nil)
          (setq pbol (point-at-bol))
          (setq peol (point-at-eol))
          (catch 'found
            (mapcar
              (lambda (x)
                (when
                  (or
                    (and
                      (>= (car x) pbol)
                      (<= (car x) peol))
                    (and
                      (>= (cdr x) pbol)
                      (<= (cdr x) peol)))
                  (setq mc t)
                  (throw 'found (message "MC exists:  %s" line))))
              my-list))
          (unless (or mc (= line starting-line))
            (message "No real or fake cursor here:  %s" line))
          (when (= 1 line) (throw 'done nil))
          (re-search-backward "\n" nil t))))))

(add-to-list 'mc--default-cmds-to-run-once 'mc/kill-all-lines-without-cursors)
```

Comment: One closely related question with an answer that would be a potential solution to the OP is the following: Say you want to kill the region selected by all cursors and yank it all on a new, empty buffer. How do you do that with multiple-cursors? Note that a simple paste on the new buffer does not work, since it only seems to yank the region from the first cursor. If we had a way to solve this particular and more natural problem, we could use it to solve the OP problem: The new buffer would only retain the selected text, so it would be equivalent to "keeping only the lines with the cursors".

Comment: I believe the answer above is indeed a complete answer to the initial question posed by the original poster, with the only difference being that messages are used instead of `kill-region`.  The instructions in the answer provide for a method to replace the messages with `kill-region`.  The comment above this one poses a *new* question, that should (in my opinion) be asked in *new* separate thread.

Comment: As noted/suggested, I asked that question [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10879/copying-text-selected-by-multiple-cursors-to-a-new-buffer).