# Copying text selected by multiple cursors to a new buffer

Tags: multiple-cursors

Say we want to kill the region selected by all cursors in multiple-cursors, and yank it all to a new, empty buffer. How do you do that with multiple-cursors?

Note that a simple copy and paste of the text on the new buffer does **not** work, since it only yanks the region from the first cursor (as reported [here](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/issues/189)).

**Note:** This question is motivated by the answer and problem presented in:
[Keeping only the lines with the cursors in multiple-cursors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/keeping-only-the-lines-with-the-cursors-in-multiple-cursors/10841?noredirect=1#comment16825_10841)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once text has been killed, exit multiple-cursor (`enter`) and while in new buffer hit `C-x r y` (normally the killed text is in the rectangle kill-ring)

Comment: After thousands of time failing to yank all the killed things I am frustrated to find that one MUST exit multiple-cursor to make `C-x r y` work. :(

Comment: The killed text in the first time persists somehow, is there something like a "cache" that I need to clear? Thanks!

Comment: I consider this solution to be ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just select text using multiple cursors and hit C-c. Just like in any other normal editor these days.

```
(setq *cutom/bulk-clipboard* nil)

(mc/load-lists)
(push 'custom/copy-across-cursors
      mc/cmds-to-run-once)
(push 'cua-copy-region
      mc/cmds-to-run-once)


(defun custom/copy-across-cursors ()
  (interactive)
  (mc/save-excursion
   (mc/save-window-scroll
    (mc/for-each-fake-cursor
     (save-excursion
       (custom/copy-across-cursor cursor)))))
  (mc--reset-read-prompts)
  (push (buffer-substring
         (caar (region-bounds))
         (cdar (region-bounds)))
        *cutom/bulk-clipboard*)
  (kill-new (s-chomp (loop for x in *cutom/bulk-clipboard*
                           concat (concat x "\n"))))
  (setq *cutom/bulk-clipboard* nil))

(defun custom/copy-across-cursor (cursor)
  (let ((mc--executing-command-for-fake-cursor t)
        (id (overlay-get cursor 'mc-id))
        (annoying-arrows-mode nil)
        (smooth-scroll-margin 0))
    (mc/add-fake-cursor-to-undo-list
     (mc/pop-state-from-overlay cursor)
     (ignore-errors
       (custom/cursor-handle-copy)
       (mc/create-fake-cursor-at-point id)))))

(defun custom/cursor-handle-copy ()
  (when (region-active-p)
    (push (buffer-substring
           (caar (region-bounds))
           (cdar (region-bounds)))
          *cutom/bulk-clipboard*))
  (when deactivate-mark (deactivate-mark)))


(advice-add #'cua-copy-region
            :around (lambda (oldfn &rest args)
                      (if (> (mc/num-cursors) 1)
                          (custom/copy-across-cursors)
                        (apply oldfn args))))
```

Please, note that dependency on library [s](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) is present.
Also this code expects you use CUA mode. If not, you must customize advice definition at the bottom.

Comment: didn't work for me. After I select the regions, enter CUA mode, a command buffer just loads, even calling `custom/copy-across-cursors` I get an error marker does not point anywhere